# Updating a UILabel via protocol results in crash (found nil)

Tags: ios, swift

I want to implement the MVP pattern for a new app. So the View shouldn't have any logic besides one that exclusively concerns UI elements. Therefore I want to request initial data from an "Interpreter" (interpreting user input in later code), which in turn requests data from my model and gives it to the "Presenter". The presenter holds a protocol with functions of the view.

The problem is: Calling `updateUIData()` from the presenter results in a

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

while calling the function from within the View at the same position is working just fine.

I suspect the error comes from the initialization of the specific MainViewController in the init of the presenter, but I don't know how to resolve this, if my guess is right.

Here's my (relevant) code:

MainViewController:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var interpreter = Interpreter() // lazy needed b/c Interpreter holds Presenter which holds MainViewController

    @IBOutlet var dateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var totalTimeLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // updateUIData()
        requestData()
    }

    func requestData() {
        interpreter.requestData()
    }

}

extension MainViewController: MainViewSetters {

    func updateUIData() {
        dateLabel.text = "Data"
        totalTimeLabel.text = "loaded"
    }

}
```

MainViewSetters (Protocol):

```
protocol MainViewSetters {
    func updateUIData()
}
```

Interpreter:

```
class Interpreter {

    let presenter = Presenter()

    func requestData() {
        // normally: get data from model and pass it to presenter
        presenter.presentData()
    }

}
```

Presenter:

```
class Presenter {

    let mainView: MainViewSetters

    init(withMainViewController mainVC: MainViewSetters = MainViewController()) {
        mainView = mainVC
    }

    func presentData() {
        mainView.updateUIData()   
    }

}
```

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: the error is at `dateLabel.text = "Data"` in `updateUIData()` in the MainViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is that you are not passing the reference to `MainViewController` to your instance of `Presenter`.

This code :

```
lazy var interpreter = Interpreter()
```

Should be more like this : (Type is needed here because with lazy the compiler can't infer properly)

```
lazy var interpreter: Interpreter = Interpreter(for: self)
```

You then have to create a special initializer in `Interpreter` which will pass the viewController instance to its `presenter` property :

```
class Interpreter {

    let presenter: Presenter

    init(for viewController: MainViewSetters) {
        presenter = Presenter(withMainViewController: viewController)
    }

    func requestData() {
        // normally: get data from model and pass it to presenter
        presenter.presentData()
    }

}
```

I also highly suggest you to remove the default value to `Presenter`'s `init` method, it's very unlikely you'll want to assign a random instance of `MainViewController` as `mainView` of any `Presenter` object.

Finally, please note that this code is creating a retain cycle and neither your `MainViewController` instance nor your `Presenter` instance will be deallocated. This is due to the fact the `Presenter` class holds a strong reference to the `MainViewController` instance with its property `mainView`. To fix this you have to mark the `mainView` as **weak** as well as making it **optional**.

Please see the fixed implementation below :

```
class Presenter {

    weak var mainView: MainViewSetters?

    init(withMainViewController mainVC: MainViewSetters) {
        mainView = mainVC
    }

    func presentData() {
        mainView?.updateUIData()
    }

}
```

For `weak` to be acceptable on a property of type `MainViewSetters` (which is not a real type but only a protocol) you have to specify that its a protocol that will only be applied to classes :

```
protocol MainViewSetters: class {
    func updateUIData()
}
```

Comment: Your suggestions brings me a step further. However: Now I get another error:

`Could not cast value of type '(NSObject) -> (()) -> it_e_TimeTrack.MainViewController' (0x11c74e080) to 'it_e_TimeTrack.MainViewSetters' (0x11c750018).`

I have to cast self to the MainViewSetters-protocol which it definitely conforms to. I tried moving the conformance from the extension to the main block of the UIViewController. That however doesn't change the error I get.

Comment: directly on `lazy var interpreter = Interpreter(for: self as! MainViewSetters)`

Comment: @BennoKress Please see my last update on the answer (the part where I explain how to use lazy var)

Comment: yes, that worked, thank you. I'm curious why, though ... can you explain that?

also: to help others, I will mark your answer as correct, but your Interpreter needs an adjustment for the initializer because of your latest edit ;) should be something like `init(for viewController: MainViewSetters)` now.

Comment: I'm not perfectly sure about the explanation but I think the inference couldn't predict accurately what you were trying to do. Another way to write it would be `lazy var interpreter: Interpreter = Interpreter(for: self)` with enough information for the compiler to guess the right way to use the `Interpreter` init method. Could you try this and I'll update my answer if it works aswell.

Comment: @BennoKress Forgot to mention you in my previous comment.

Comment: That also works, is understandable and looks much nicer. As a side note: the `weak` reference in the Presenter is not possible for my case, because `'weak' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types, not 'MainViewSetters'`. In my case I don't really care about that, because I will have no other view than the Main View. Also: Sorry for not upvoting your answer, but my reputation is not high enough to cast votes ...

Comment: @BennoKress I'm good don't worry. You could use `weak` but then you'd have to change your protocol definition to this : `protocol MainViewSetters: class`.

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing interpreter passing a default MainViewController().
Change that code from:

```
lazy var interpreter = Interpreter()
```

to

```
lazy var interpreter = Interpreter(withMainViewController: self)
```

Comment: this answer points in the right direction, however as noted in the answer to Fantattitude the problem is a bit more complex ... he solved it now luckily :)